# How to force inline-blocked divs to same height

Tags: jquery, alignment, height, css

i have inline-blocked divs like a grid. i would like to force all of them which are in the same line to the same height, they should get the height of the longest div.

Css, jquery or simple javascript solution would be great.

It is something very common nowadays... i went to have a look at Masonry but as far as i understood on the sample graphics, it does not align like this... am i right ?

The blog in question : http://ildesign-blogger-demo-1.blogspot.fr/

The HTML :

```
<div class="container>
    <div class="inline">text</div>
    <div class="inline">text + image</div>
    <div class="inline">text</div>
    <div class="inline">whatever</div>
    <div class="inline">text + image</div>
    <div class="inline">text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS :

```
.container {width: 100%; display:block;} 
.inline {display: inline-block; width: 28%; margin: 1%; padding: 1%;}
```

So, there are three inline divs in each line, i would like the lines beeing aligned, so the inline divs should have the same height like the longest div in the line...

Edit : I re-edited this post to add that the html is generated by a Blogger xml template. So, if you suggest to add each three inline divs into a div which will be like a row, i do not know how to do it... the original xml code :

```
<div class='blog-posts hfeed'>
  <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>
  <data:defaultAdStart/>
  <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <div class='date-outer'>
      <h2 class='date-header'><span><data:post.timestamp/></span></h2>
      <div class='date-posts'>
        <div class='post-outer'>
          <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </div>
        <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
            <data:defaultAdEnd/>
          <b:else/>
            <data:adEnd/>
          </b:if>
          <div class='inline-ad'><data:adCode/></div>
          <data:adStart/>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:post.trackLatency'>
          <data:post.latencyJs/>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </b:loop>
<data:adEnd/>
</div>
```

So the **.blog-posts** = **.container** and the **.date-outer** = **.inline** in my above html example...

Masonry can do it ? 
Or a jquery code for making a grid with equal heights ?

Comment: If display: inline-block is really what you need - just disable text wrapping to keep you height constant. Or use min-height (probably at nested table content level) or you might be able specifying right for inline-block element just try it up.

Comment: quick tip - instead of defining class="inline" for all those child divs, you could instead, in your css, write .container div{}

Comment: @user3455395 : min-height seems somehow a good alternative... can you explain me the text-wrapping a bit more ? i do not use to do it... 
lukeocom : why is it better ? 
I go to sleep, i will look at the answers tomorrow... and thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: @Igor Laszlo min-height won't save ya from unwanted wrapping of you table-cell elements when the layout runs out of space.

Comment: @user3455395 : min-height is possible but it is not a nice solution as it should be changed at different responsive points (@media only screen and...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a jquery plugin which makes the divs in equal height of the height of the tallest div. There are a lot on the web but not all of them work. I have found one which works perfectly : https://github.com/johnnyfaldo/equal-heights-responsive

It needs four .js files :

- jquery.js
- underscore.js
- html5shiv.js
- equal-heights-responsive.js

To initiate the plugin :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.elements-to-equalise').equalHeights({
            responsive:true,
            animate:true,
            animateSpeed:500
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`display: inline-block` style is designed for something else, here's an example of what it's been designed for (`inline` is a separate dispay mode, so I'd recommend to rename you class to `inline-block` regardless of which way you're gonna proceed with - for now I used your namings):

Create this with 100 cells:

```
<div class='block'>
    <div class="inline" style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'>1</div>
    <div class="inline" style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'>2</div>
    <div class="inline" style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'>3</div>
..
    <div class="inline" style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'>100</div>
</div>
```

then resize the window and watch how boxes get layout.

What you need is a table, either a regular one:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>First Col Content</div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div>Second Col Content</div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div>Third Col Content</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

or a CSS one:

```
<div style='display: table;'>
 <div style='display: table-row;'>
  <div style='display: table-cell; width: 33%; min-width: 33%;'>
   <div>First Col Content</div>
  </div >
  <div style='display: table-cell; width: 33%; min-width: 33%;'>
   <div>Second Col Content</div>
  </div >
  <div style='display: table-cell; width: 34%; min-width: 34%;'>
   <div>Third Col Content</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, so like @Notulysses, you say that i need to create rows too... i will check my Blogger template if i will be able to do this in the part of this or if it is generated by xml, in that case i will not be able to change it... 
It is 3h30 am, i will let you know tomorroiw if it works and how... thanks a lot !

Comment: inline-block is about getting the best of both inline and block displays. it doesn't guarantee the same height. tables-cell are guaranteed to have it. Also try resizing your layout - make it extremely narrow and see what happens.

Comment: so, i checked the blogger template and i do not have any idea how to code it for generate rows after each 3 inline divs. i guess i should write a `<b:if>` condition in the xml `<loop>`, i can not do it...

Answer (score 1):

Very simple jQuery plugin which also includes automatically resizing elements when window size is changed.

Change **.my-inline-block-class** to a jQuery selector that will select your inline-block elements.

```
(function($, window) {
    var $ls;
    function autoheight() {
        var max = 0;
        $ls.each(function() {
            $t = $(this);
            $t.css('height','');
            max = Math.max(max, $t.height());
        });
        $ls.height(max);
    }
    $(function() {
        $ls = $('.my-inline-block-class'); // the inline-block selector
        autoheight(); // first time
        $ls.on('load', autoheight); // when images in content finish loading
        $(window).load(autoheight); // when all content finishes loading
        $(window).resize(autoheight); // when the window size changes
    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try it and i will come back... not nowadays but in a week i guess... thanks again !

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I had written a similar function myself in the past but much more complicated than it needed to be. One thing I would add is $(window).load(autoheight); works better than, or at least in addition to, $ls.on('load', autoheight); for picking up all images loading.