# Matching height of two inline divs with just CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm working on a grid and I am trying to figure out how to make two divs, which are `display:inline-block` match each other in height. Is this possible using just CSS?

For example see this JS Fiddle here. The green area I would like to be 100% of it's container, so that it matches the left container.

http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/kqtLkkz6/

The divs use the following grid CSS:

```
.grid {
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:0%;
}
.grid.golden-small {
    width:61.8%;
}
.grid.golden-large {
    width:38.2%;
}
```

I tried explicitly stating the height of the parent container, by doing `height:auto` so that it would fit to the content inside it, but this didn't seem to work. See my second example here:

```
section {
    height:auto; /* and added this */
}
.featured-post .featured-text {
    height:100%; /* added this */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/kqtLkkz6/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force inline-blocked divs to same height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377639/how-to-force-inline-blocked-divs-to-same-height)

Comment: @sdcr No I do not want to layout my site using <table>

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand the question before, now I get it, is it ok to add the green background to `.featured-post`?

Comment: yeah, `table-cell` helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I where you I would make a table instead. inline positioning is very difficult to use. I would try remake it by making a parent element that contains all the elements you want to stack inline to `display:table;` and the child elements to `display:table-cell;` play around with it is my advice

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.

Set the display of your parent element to table, `.featured-post {display: table;}` and the display of the child elements to table-cell, `.grid {display: table-cell;}` I guess this is the easiest solution (you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/kqtLkkz6/3/)) It will work at least that you set `position:absolute` but I don't think that's your case.